# Failed to Recover from Panic during mutex lock and unlock

Tags: go, mutex, panic

I am trying to check if i can recover panic from this code:
I have deliberately added mutex.Unlock() at line x

```
func main() {
   defer panicHandler()
   x := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
   var mutex sync.Mutex
   mutex.Lock()
   defer mutex.Unlock()
   fmt.Println(x[2])
   mutex.Unlock()    // line x
}

func panicHandler() {
   rec := recover()
   if rec != nil {
       fmt.Println("Panic occurred - ", rec)
   }
}
```

It is giving -
fatal error: sync: unlock of unlocked mutex

Moreover the flow didnt go inside panicHandler.
Can anyone help me to understand this

I was expecting control flow to go inside the panicHandler() method and get recovered but it didnt happen this

Comment: A `fatal error` is not a panic, you cannot recover from that.

Answer (score -2):

You are calling `mutex.Unlock()` at the end in addition to the `defer mutex.Unlock()`. So when the defer runs, it's already unlocked! Just delete:

```
mutex.Unlock()    // line x
```

It didn't goto panic because that's for runtime errors like accessing something that's nil. This is a FATAL error and you can't recover from that.

Comment: thanks for the answer. So is it that we cant recover from fatal errors

Comment: When Panic happens you can't recover it.